# Incrementing the value in multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I couldn't understand the multidimensional array in PHP properly. I have a CSV file having two columns as shown below:

[image]

I am trying to create an array of array, in which each key is a *cataegory*. However, the value of each key is an array. In this array, each key is *company* and value is the count of the product. See below the code:

```
<?php
//array contains value
function contains_value($my_array, $value_search){
    foreach ($my_array as $key => $value) {
        if ($value === $value_search)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
//array contains key
function contains_key($my_array, $key_search){
    foreach ($my_array as $key => $value) {
        if ($key === $key_search)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

$handle   = fopen("product_list.csv", "r");
$products = array();
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $product  = explode(",", $line);
        $category = $product[0];
        $company  = $product[1];

        if (contains_key($products, $category)) {
            if (contains_value($products, $company)) {
                //increase the count of category by 1
                $products[$category][$company] = $products[$category][$company] + 1;
            } else {
                //append new company with count 1
                array_push($products[$category], array(
                    $company,
                    1
                ));
            }
        } else {
            //initialize new company with count 1
            $products[$category] = array(
                $company,
                1
            );
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

var_dump($products);
?>
```

I noticed that the `var_dump($products)` is not showing correction information. I am expecting following kind of result:
[image]

Comment: An "array of array" or a multidimensional array doesn't have a key; you must be thinking of an associative array. Could you show us the structure of the final output?

Comment: Show us what the results need to look like.

Comment: Please have a look in the updated question. I just added sample output. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't enough reputation to reply, but I think he need counts.

To complete the answer of Alive to Die, more something like this:

```
if (!array_key_exists($category, $products)) {
    products[$category] = [];
}

if (!array_key_exists($company, $products[$category])) {
    products[$category][$company] = 0;
}

++$results[$cataegory][$company];
```

But cleaner ;)

Edit:

If I remember well, his first idea was this:

```
$products[$category][] = $company;
```

The code is shorter. Maybe you can combine the two ideas.

Comment: Not able to see the answer given by `Alive to Die`. Can you please post that part too?

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed, it is much shorter and easier than my approach. Thanks again.